# How to create click event for dynamically created custom control?

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

Let say that I'm creating thousands of custom controls, each control has own data assigned to it (like name, id, etc.), now I would like to add

- click event for each of these custom controls
- access from software any of these dynamically created controls

So I would like to show MsgBox if user click control #452, which will be returning values assigned to object in custom control class (passed during creation of new control on user form)

Second thing is that I would like to access at any time any of these objects and read values assigned to object in control....

How to do it ? Each control has name assigned like "Example1", "Example2", "Example3" but I don't know how to access it from code as any of these exists during writing...

Also I were trying to find how to create and rise events but it seems that all solutions are for statically created controls and I need to rise events for dynamically crated custom controls....

Thanks in advance for any tips/help how to solve it.

I'm using VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out !

It is very simple actually.

If any one will be looking for an answer :

To access dynamically created control first we are going to name it :

```
Dim Control as new CustomControl
Control.Name = "Name" & Counter
```

Next after we've created new controls we are going to access it using:

```
Dim _Control as new CustomControl
_Control = Ctype(Me.Panel1.Controls("Name1"), CustomControl)
MsgBox(_Control.Name.ToString)
```

Viola

I still not sure about custom events for all controls on custom control (so where ever user click, there should be override event which returns something back, now I can only either click panel container (not labels/pictureboxes) from code inside user class, or event per control on custom control (but issue is that I want to pass data from custom control to user class).